# Fixing width of Console tab

Tags: webstorm

In WebStorm 9, I have a problem with width of console: it is oversized, so horizontal scrolling bar appears. It is particularly annoying when I want to access line if a log (the log is written on the left side, while file name and line number on the very side).

How can I resize console width?

Answer (score 3):

What you're looking for is a `soft wrap`:

Go to `File > Settings > Editor > General`, and check `Use soft wraps in console`, `Use custom soft wraps indent` and set the indent to `1`. This will wrap the console output, if the content is too long.

Comment: Great answer, I was dying inside using this freakin` console!